# spring boot 3 jpa inheritance not working properly

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

After upgrading to spring boot 3 from 2.x the JPA inheritance strategy InheritanceType.JOINED is behaving incorrectly.

I have below Entities Book and ComputerBook

Book

```
@Entity(name = "book")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
abstract class Book @JvmOverloads constructor(

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
open var id: Long,
open var author: String,
open var publisher: String
)
```

Computer Book

```
@Entity(name = "computer_book")
@DiscriminatorValue("computer")
data class ComputerBook @JvmOverloads constructor(


    override var id: Long,
    override var author: String,
    override var publisher: String,
    var language: String

): Book(
    id,
    author,
    publisher
)
```

When I get the ComputerBook entity using BookRepository I get it as follows:

```
 id = 1
 author= null
 publisher = null
 language = "Php"
 Book.id = 0
 Book.author = "Jhon Doe"
 Book.publisher = "Bright publishers"
```

but when I was using spring boot 2.x the entity I used to get was

```
 id = 1
 author= "Jhon Doe"
 publisher = "Bright publishers"
 language = "Php"
 Book.id = 0
 Book.author = null
 Book.publisher = null
```

Is this Bug in spring boot 3 or I am missing something?